# Can't label multiple rows of sns.catplot()

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Here's my source code:

```
plot = sns.catplot(x='Year',
                   y='Graduation Rate',
                   col='Group',
                   hue='Campus',
                   kind='bar',
                   col_wrap=4,
                   data=mbk_grad.sort_values(['Group', 'Campus']))

for i in np.arange(2):
    for j in np.arange(4):
        ax = plot.facet_axis(i,j) 
        for p in ax.patches:
            if str(p.get_height()) != 'nan':
                ax.text(p.get_x() + 0.06, p.get_height() * .8, '{0:.2f}%'.format(p.get_height()), color='white', rotation='vertical', size='large')

plt.show()
```

The output is the following:

[image]

How do I get the rows after the first labeled like the first row is? Why isn't my nested for-loop working?

Answer (score 5):

If you look at `plot.axes.shape`, you will see that the array of axes is not (2,4) as you are expected but (8,) a 1D array.  This is because you are using `col_wrap`, and not defining a layout grid.

```
plot = sns.catplot(x='Year',
                   y='Graduation Rate',
                   col='Group',
                   hue='Campus',
                   kind='bar',
                   col_wrap=4,
                   data=df_sum.sort_values(['Group', 'Campus']))

for i in np.arange(8):
#     for j in np.arange(4):
        ax1 = plot.facet_axis(0,i)
        for p in ax1.patches:
            if str(p.get_height()) != 'nan':
                ax1.text(p.get_x() + 0.06, p.get_height() * .8, '{0:.2f}%'.format(p.get_height()), color='white', rotation='vertical', size='large')
```

Output:

[image]

PS.  I attended Booker T. Washington (HSEP).  Where is my HISD school here?

Comment: Where did you get the dataframe from? Just curious

Comment: @Bazingaa I created it myself.  `df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2014,2015,2016]*33+[2014],
                   'Graduation Rate':.4 + np.random.random(100)*.6,
                   'Group':np.random.choice(['Asian','Black','Hispanic','Multiracial','Native American','Pacific Islander','White'],100),
                   'Campus':np.random.choice(['HISD','Kashmere H.S.','Scarbrough H.S.','Wheatley H.S.'], 100)})`

Comment: Due to the missing data in the question, I Didn’t feel like attempting it

Comment: @Bazingaa Yeah..... I understand.  I took the time to generate data.  I often skip questions due to lack of data, but this question wasn't I don't think data dependent, so I just made up some.  Plus, is related to my hometown of Houston.  So, I felt an urge.